# Ocultar uma máscara javascript

Tags: javascript, mask

Alguém sabe como se oculta os _ das mask (javascript) por exemplo no meu site fica:

Nome: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

e eu queria ocultar os "_".

```
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/…;
<script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/…;
<script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/…;
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#cc").mask("999999999999");
   $("#ciclo").mask("9999-9999");
});
```

Comment: Está usando algum plugin ?

Comment: Como você está fazendo para mostrar a máscara? Qual plugin está utilizando?

Comment: estou a usar  `  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cc").mask("999999999999");
    $("#ciclo").mask("9999-9999");
   }); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode substituir o `_` por nada  adicionamento o argumento opcional `placeholder`. Isso é indicamento na [documentação](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) do plugin

```
$("#ciclo").mask("9999-9999", {placeholder:" "});
```

Comment: Só para informar: o placeholder, define o que irá aparecer na substituição do número. Também dá pra trocar o algarismo '9' para '#', assim evita o bug em caso de preenchimento do número 9. `$("#ciclo").mask("####-####", {definitions:{'#': "[0-9]"}, placeholder:" "});` Entr outras coisas:  [veja aqui](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/blob/master/src/jquery.maskedinput.js)